# Spring and Quartz integration in cluster mode is not overwritting existing jobs

Tags: quartz-scheduler

I am using Spring 3 and Quartz 1.8.5 to schedule jobs in a clustered mode. I have placed, overwriteExistingJobs=true in the Spring's scheduler configuration.

There is a requirement for me to create dynamic jobs programmatically apart from the jobs which are part of the configuration using Quartz jobs. Everything works fine till i re-start the server. At this point , there is a problem with overwriteExistingJobs=true.

Say, if i have a dynamic job created to execute every two minutes. And, i stop the server and start it after ten minutes, the job executes five times as soon as the server starts. But, if there is a job which is part of the spring configuration , like the one given in spring documentation , it is over-written when the server re-starts.

My observation has been that for jobs which are configured in the spring configuration file and added to the org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean, the 
PREV_FIRE_TIME in QRTZ_TRIGGERS table gets updated to '-1' but for dynamically created jobs it is not over-written.

Answer (score 1):

The fix is as follows:

a) I have CronTriggers associated with dynamic jobs so what i did was to provide the mis-fire instruction.

```
JobDetail jobDetail = new JobDetail(job.getDescription(), job.getName(),job.getClass());
CronTrigger crTrigger = new CronTrigger( "cronTrigger", job.getName(), cronExpression);
crTrigger.setStartTime(firstFireTime);
crTrigger.setMisfireInstruction(CronTrigger.MISFIRE_INSTRUCTION_DO_NOTHING);
scheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail, crTrigger);
```

b)The mis-fire threshold was pretty high (6000000). So, what i did was to reduce the misfire threshold and it worked like a charm.